# Regular Expression - Match pattern that does not contain a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm quite new to regular expression, and have been searching around for away to do this without success. Given a string, I want to remove any pattern that starts with "abc", ends with "abc", and does not contain "abc" in the middle. If I do

```
'abc.*(abc).*abc'
```

it will match any patter starts with "abc", ends with "abc", and does contain "abc" in the middle. How do I do the opposite. I try

```
'abc.*^(abc).*abc'
```

but it won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax for trying to negate part of your pattern is incorrect.

Also, `^` outside of a character class asserts position at the beginning of the string. You need to use a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertion and be sure to [anchor](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) the entire pattern.

```
^abc(?:(?!abc).)*abc$
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eP2tR1/1)

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry I can't upvote the answer. May I ask you a follow up, so this works for
        re.match('^abc(?:(?!abc).)*abc$','abc222abc')
But if I want to do this multiline, it seems not to work
        re.match('^abc(?:(?!abc).)*abc$','111/nabc222abc/nxyz/n', flags = re.MULTILINE). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hey sorry I'm new to the site, and I thought I can accept both answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. And use `re.search()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the following pattern :

```
^abc((?!abc).)*abc$
```

`(?!abc)` is [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - Assert that it is impossible to match the `abc` inside your string.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hWKIz2oVVwrQ1XnE)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kasra and sorry I can't upvote answer, nor can I accept both.