# Regex not to capture if a string contains a word before it

Tags: python, regex

I want to select the word "hazardous" only if it is a separate word and not with "non " or "non-"before it.

eg:

**non-hazardous**

**non hazardous**

**hazardous**

**non agricultural hazardous**

```
regex 1: ^(?!non[-/s]?)hazardous$
regex 2: ^(?!non-|non\s)hazardous$
```

I tried the above two regex and it gave correct results for the first 3 sentences, but it's not selecting hazardous in 4th sentence.
I want to select hazardous in 4th sentence as it doesn't have "non " or "non-" before it

Reference: [Regular Expression - Match pattern that does not contain a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652581/regular-expression-match-pattern-that-does-not-contain-a-string)

Comment: Maybe just `r'\b(?<!\bnon[-\s])hazardous\b'`? See https://regex101.com/r/qmGLvQ/1

Comment: It is explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'\b(?<!\bnon[-\s])hazardous\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmGLvQ/1). The pattern matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bnon[-\s])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `non-` or `non` and a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `hazardous` - a string
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: why is there a word boundary in front of everything? Can you explain in detail

Comment: @ConMan77 In order to [match the whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1324676/3832970).

Comment: (?<!\bnon-|non\s)hazardous\b can this be used ?

Comment: @ConMan77 Yes if it works for you, but the alternation inside an unanchored lookbehind is resource consuming. Using character classes is more efficient when possible,

Comment: I often see `\s` used in place of a space where the only relevant whitespace character is a space. Your regex does not match `"One is non\nhazardous"`, but arguably should. That's a contrived example, of course (and here it's hard to see how the use of `\s` could cause a problem), but it seems to me that, as a rule, one should always use  a space rather than `\s` when a space is the only whitespace character that is to be matched or not matched. Your opinion?

Comment: @CarySwoveland What about non-breaking spaces? The `\x20` won't match them. `\s` is default for any space in the regex world. Unless it is stated that only a literal space is meant, I'd use `\s`.